# LED flashing on Hot start

Tags: led, flashing

I have kitchen lights using 12v 5w leds (GU 5.3). There is a 30w 12v led power supply. When switching off, then back on, the lights flash. Any ideas please. There are 2 sets in the room, they both do the same. Leave it 10 minutes, then its fine...All connections are tight, no dim switches anywhere. Your thoughts please...

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. You might try measuring the voltage coming out of the power supply when running, and when you turn it off how the voltage decreases over time. You may find that adding a (large) resistor will drain off the power more quickly.

Comment: maybe they are supposed to flash like that ..... it could be an attention getting function ..... i've seen light bulbs that do that .... the bulbs were meant to go into an outside fixture .... if you had an emergency and called for an ambulance, you would flick the light off/on and the light bulb would start flashing

Comment: How many bulbs are there and what wattage (actual) are they?  If you remove one, does the problem clear up?